# What is making my constructor protected?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
#ifndef SLIST_H
#define SLIST_H
#include "llist.h"

using namespace std;

class slist:public llist{

 public:
  slist();
  int search(el_t Key);
  void replace(el_t Elem, int I);
};
#endif
```

That is my new class I just made that gives me the search and replace function, on top of all the inherited functions contained in llist.h

In my main...

```
#include "slist.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  slist list;
  list.addFront(4);
  cout<<list.search(4);
}
```

I'm trying to call addfront() which is a public function in the llist class. Then I want to call search() which is an inherited public function of the slist class. g++ gives me a few errors that I don't understand.

```
slist.h: In function âint main()â:
slist.h:10: error: âslist::slist()â is protected
main.cpp:7: error: within this context
```

slist() is protected? Why's that? I put it under public:

Also whats up with the this context, I'm guessing I'm just doing the whole inheritance thing totally wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here's the llist class, if it helps

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class llist{
 protected:

   typedef int el_t;
   el_t total;

  struct Node{
    int Elem;
    Node *Next;
  };

  Node *Front;
  Node *Rear;
  Node * Curr;

public:
 class Overflow{};
 class Underflow{};
 class Range{};
 llist();
 ~llist();
 bool isEmpty();
 void displayAll();
 void addRear(el_t NewNum);
 void deleteFront(el_t& OldNum);
 void addFront(el_t NewNum);
 void deleteRear(el_t& OldNum);
 void deleteIth(int I, el_t& OldNum);
 void addbeforeIth(int I, el_t newNum);
 class Overflow;

};
#endif
```

### This is llist.cpp with only the relevant functions pasted

```
#include "llist.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int total=0;

llist::llist(){
    Front=NULL;
    Rear=NULL;
    total=0;
}

llist::~llist(){
  while(Front!=NULL){
    int z;
    deleteFront(z);
  }
}
bool llist::isEmpty(){
if(Front==NULL){
  return true;
}
return false;
}
void llist::displayAll(){
 Curr=Front;
 if(isEmpty()){
   cout<<"[ empty ]"<<endl;
 }else{
  while(Curr!=NULL){\
    cout<<"curr != NuL"<<endl;
    cout<<Curr->Elem<<endl;
    Curr=Curr->Next;
  }
 }
 }



void llist::addFront(el_t NewNum){
    if(isEmpty()){
       Node *x=new Node;
       x->Next=Front;
       Rear=Front;
       Front=x;
       Front->Elem=NewNum;
        }else{
      Node *x=new Node;
      x->Next=Front;
      Front=x;
      Front->Elem=NewNum;
      ++total;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post `llist`? I think this might be required here. Ideally, produce an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Is that all the code you have?

Comment: llist is pretty big but I will post it

Comment: @Tyler: Please, take the time to read the link I have posted in my comment above. You should try to reduce the amount of code you post to the smallest size that is required to reproduce the problem. Don't just post the entire class. Strip everything from it that is not relevant.

Comment: Don't write `using namespace std` in headers, please. Ever.

Comment: Is the constructor for llist protected?

Comment: Had to hack it about a bit, but [cannot replicate](http://codepad.org/XwAKc7UL). Make a testcase like that that exhibits the problem. This is called _debugging_.

Comment: @KelseyRider: Wouldn't matter, and the error would be different.

Comment: Is llist class template? If yes then declaration of slist should look differently. Also **remove `using namespace std` from headers**!!

Comment: Make sure the files are saved and try a recompile?

Comment: It's better you show `llist.h` source code.

Comment: @TylerPfaff: Alas, you have not read [the link](http://sscce.org). You have given us a bunch of badly formatted, incomplete code that lacks exactly the information we need (we need the declarations, the stuff in the header-file, not the definitions). Please, put some more effort into this.

Comment: posted it all, sorry about that

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you are (a) not saving the file before compiling (b) saving it under a different name/path :). If there is e.g. a Makefile involved, carefully look at `make -Bsn` to spot any surprising logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly can't see the problem but not every compiler is standard-compliant, so I would try the following:

1) Rename your class - if it works, that means it's a because of a naming conflict.

2) Remove the using directives.

3) Remove the inheritance. If it works after this... you really need to change compilers.

4) Try `#undef public` before your class declaration. If it works after this... well, someone's in for a talk with the manager.

5) Pray...

Comment: The exact same code compiled under visual studio. Sadly, it has to compile with g++ for my class.